# Django REST Framework: passing context to a nested serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

I've a pair of parent-child models/serializers/viewsets - Tool and ToolInput:

`models.py:`

```
class Tool(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10000, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    base_command = jsonfield.JSONField(verbose_name="baseCommand")

class ToolInput(models.Model):
    tool = models.ForeignKey(Tool, related_name="inputs", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10000, primary_key=True)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)
    type = jsonfield.JSONField()
```

`serializers.py`

```
class ToolSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializerMixin,
                     serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField()
    inputs = ToolInputSerializer(many=True)
    baseCommand = serializers.JSONField(source="base_command")

    class Meta:
        model = Tool
        fields = ('id', 'inputs', 'baseCommand')

class ToolInputSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializerMixin,
                          serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ToolInput
        fields = ('id', 'label', 'description', 'type')
```

`views.py:`

```
class ToolViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Tool.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = ToolSerializer

class ToolInputViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = ToolInputSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        tool_id = self.kwargs['tool_id']
        return ToolInput.objects.filter(tool_id=tool_id)

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(ToolInputViewSet, self).get_serializer_context()
        context["tool"] = Tool.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['tool_id'])
        return context
```

As you can see, I use `ToolInputSerializer` both as a standalone serializer for `ToolInputViewSet` and as a nested serializer within `ToolViewSet`.

When `ToolInputSerializer` is used as a nested serializer in `ToolViewSet`, it somehow automagically receives the value of `tool` argument and assigns it to `ToolInput` model's `tool` field (by the way, I feel that it's a totally wrong behavior from  architectural point of view - there's no such field as `tool` on `ToolInputSerializer` at all and DRF's filling the respective model's field - it should bail out with a `Field Does Not Exist` error IMO and at least require a write-only field `tool` on serializer).

But when I use it as a standalone serializer in `ToolInputViewSet`, I want to assign the value of `ToolInput` model's `tool` field to `Tool` instance, determined by `tool_id` url parameter, received by `ToolInputViewSet` in kwargs.

I'm trying to pass the value of that field with serializer context, overriding `ToolInputViewSet.get_serializer_context()` method, but it's not working. How to do that properly?

---

Sidenote: I'm pretty tired of the messy and inconsistent, non-uniform automagic of DRF's context handling that pierces layers of Model-Serializer-Field-View architecture. It really needs to be more explicit and customizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the context, I still don't know how to make it work.

As for how nested serializers work, this is my bad: as you can see, I inherit all the ViewSets from my custom `WritableNestedModelSerializerMixin`, where I've overridden `create()` and `update()` methods to work with nested data structures, so this is my tinkering.

So, as a workaround, I created a separate `StandaldonToolInputSerializer` and modified ToolInputViewSet, adding the missing `tool` field to serializer and automatically patching `request.data` with the Tool reference:

`serializers.py`

```
class StandaloneToolInputSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    tool = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        write_only=True,
        many=False,
        queryset=Tool.objects.all()
    )
    inputBinding = serializers.JSONField(source="input_binding")

    class Meta:
        model = ToolInput
        fields = ('id', 'tool', 'label', 'description', 'type', 'inputBinding')
```

`views.py`

```
class ToolInputViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    '''
    Describes a Tool input.
    '''
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = StandaloneToolInputSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        tool_id = self.kwargs['tool_id']
        return ToolInput.objects.filter(tool_id=tool_id)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data["tool"] = self.kwargs['tool_id']
        return super(ToolInputViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data["tool"] = self.kwargs['tool_id']
        return super(ToolInputViewSet, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```